# How to I draw or build up a mesh in 3d for an animation?

Tags: animation, mesh

I have been trying to animate a concept logo in a complicated way, but I am not sure what search terms I would use to find the appropriate tutorials on this. Below I have an example setup that highlights the issue.

Let us say that I have an SVG of a donut (a 2d torus) that I imported in, extruded out, and then converted to a mesh. What I want to do is to have a glowing ball draw out the mesh torus.

What I mean, imagine the torus as an analog clock. At frame 0, the ball is at 12'o clock, and I see 0% of the torus. At frame 30, the ball is at 3'o clock and I see 25% of the torus, so on until frame 120 where the ball disappears and I see the 100% of the torus.

I know the basics of Blender well as I have been playing with it for weeks, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. For the ball, I suspect it will be a simple follow path that I could draw out and sync with the torus growth (I can do this). For the torus, I originally tried to use Boolean Modifiers against the sphere, but the torus does not stay shown once the ball passes over (that would violate "Boolean").

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want some kind of sonar/radar effect where the mesh is revealed by the sweeping motion ? Have you explored a custom shader instead of trying to modify the mesh ?

Comment: how does your torus look like? could it be made with an array along a curve?

Comment: screenshots or a sketch what you like to have would be a great help. And your blend file would help too.

Comment: @moonboots I. have tried the array method prior but it crashed my machine and when it did work, the effect was a bit choppy. Chris's answer below is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shift-A -> Curve -> Circle
2. uncheck cyclic

[image]

[image]

3. Tab -> select point -> R -> Z -> rotate like so

[image]

4. select point -> R -> Z -> rotate like so:

[image]

5. E -> Shift-Z -> move like so:

[image]

6. R -> Z -> rotate like so:

[image]

7. tab
8. give some depth

[image]

9. select cirlce -> R -> Y -> 180
10. keyframe factor end 0 at frame 0
11. keyframe factor end 1 at frame 120

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I am looking for

Comment: You are welcome